# Text in multirow overlaps the next row

Tags: tables, multirow

Suppose, I want to create a table like this:

[image]

I decided to use `\multirow` with `\newline`. But the `\multirow` cell is not stretched vertically:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|m{2cm}|m{2cm}|}
  \hline
  \multirow{2}{2cm}{line 1
      \newline
      line 2 line 2 line 2 line 2} &
  1\\
  \hhline{|~|-|}
  & 2\\
  \hline
  text & text\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

How to fix?

Comment: muiltirow does not know how long the contained text is. You simply need to give it another row -> 3.

Comment: @MartinH It works. But is it the only option?

Comment: I've yet to see a table using `\multirow` that can't be improved by removing `\multirow`. ;-) In any case, if you say your cell has to span two rows, but the text in it is longer than two rows, you have to arrange things so that there's no overlap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It often works better to make the large entry a normal cell and then separately arrange the vertical stacking of the other material with a nested tabular or, here just as paragraphs.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{hhline}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|m{2cm}|m{2cm}|}
  \hline
  line 1 line 1 line 2 line 2 line 2 line 2&
  1
  \medskip\hrule\medskip
   2\\
  \hline
  text & text\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

You may need to adjust the vertical spacing to your needs. As suggested in chat, this produces a 2 closer to the line, and makes the line extend to touch the vertical rules.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{hhline}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|}
  \hline
  line 1 line 1 line 2 line 2 line 2 line 2&
  1
  \par\medskip\nointerlineskip\hbox to \hsize{\kern-\tabcolsep\hrulefill\kern-\tabcolsep}
  \vspace{-1mm}
  2\\
  \hline
  text & text\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How to get rid of the padding between the vertical and horizontal lines: `\medskip\hrule\medskip`?

Comment: @user4035 several ways eg  `\par\medskip\nointerlineskip\hbox to \hsize{\kern-\tabcolsep\hrulefill\kern-\tabcolsep}\medskip`

Comment: What instructions control the space between the line and 2? I removed the last \medskip - the gap became smaller.

Comment: it should  be a normal baselineskip from the line to the baseline of the 2, plus any additional space (I used \medskip but you could use \vspace{1pt} or whatever you want

Answer (score 1):

The table you want to create doesn't require `\multirow`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
        \hline
        line 1 & 1\\
        \cline{2-2}
        line 2 line 2 & 2\\
        line 2 line 2 &\\
        \hline
        text & text\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]