# The cell is not stretched vertically in longtabu

Tags: vertical-alignment, multirow, longtabu, miktex2.9, cell

We have a latex `longtabu` with `multirow` cells and these cells contain a lot of text. 
BTW XeLaTeX is used.

**Problem:** cell is not stretched vertically.

Why?
How can I fix it?

I have tried to use 
`\par\medskip\nointerlineskip\hbox to \hsize{\kern-\tabcolsep\hrulefill\kern-\tabcolsep} \vspace{-1mm}` , but the line is offset in 5 and 6 cells.

And I tried solution from [response](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/113732/141717), but in this case, one row of cells will be very wide.

**Desired result:**[image]
**Actual result:** [image]

**Minimal working example:**

```
\documentclass[10pt, oneside, a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[left=2cm,right=1.5cm,
top=2cm,bottom=2cm,bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{metalogo} 
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{color,colortbl}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{DarkBlue}{HTML}{074396} 
\definecolor{Blue}{HTML}{1C8CCC}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Arial}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\chbody}[1]{\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\color{Blue}\bfseries}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}
\newcommand{\ch}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\chbody{#1}}}
\newcommand{\fch}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\chbody{#1}}}

\tabulinesep=2mm

\arrayrulecolor{DarkBlue}

 \begin{longtabu} to 170 mm {
    |X[1.2, c]
    |X[2 ] 
    |X[2, c] 
    |X[1.5, c]
    |X[1.5, c] 
    |X[2, c] 
    |X[4]| 
    }

\arrayrulecolor{DarkBlue}
\hline

\fch{ID}
& \ch{Message}
& \ch{Mode}
& \ch{Priority} 
& \ch{ Category}  
& \ch{Escalation} 
& \ch{Recommended actions}
 \\ 
\hline

10003 
& ALARM test. Press ALARM button for stop alarm 
& All 
& Alarm  
& A 
& Alarm 
&  Confirm 
 \\ 
\hline

\multirow{2}{=}{10007} 
& \multirow{2}{=}{PORT rudder feedback fail. Check steering system} 
& \textcolor{Blue}{\textbf{S}} 
& Caution 
& B  
& *  
& \multirow{2}{=}{Switch to MAN, check steering system} 
\\ 

\tabucline{3-6}

&  
& \textcolor{Blue}{\textbf{A, F, O}} 
& Warning 
& B 
& Alarm 
& 
 \\ 

\hline

\multirow{2}{=}{10007} 
& \multirow{2}{=}{PORT rudder feedback fail. Check steering system} 
& \textcolor{Blue}{\textbf{S}} 
& Caution 
& B  
& *  
& \multirow{2}{=}{Switch to MAN, check steering system} 
\\ 

\tabucline{3-6}

&  
& \textcolor{Blue}{\textbf{A, F, O}} 
& Warning 
& B 
& Alarm 
& 
 \\ 

\hline
\multirow{2}{=}{10007} 
& \multirow{2}{=}{PORT rudder feedback fail. Check steering system} 
& \textcolor{Blue}{\textbf{S}} 
& Caution 
& B  
& *  
& \multirow{2}{=}{Switch to MAN, check steering system} 
\\ 

\tabucline{3-6}

&  
& \textcolor{Blue}{\textbf{A, F, O}} 
& Warning 
& B 
& Alarm 
& 
 \\ \hline

\end{longtabu}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not really an automated solution, but setting `\tabulinesep=6mm` seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have more lines in the `multirow` cells than are in spanned rows.

- one (very rude) solutions is increase `\tabulinesep`, by which you compensate missing vertical space by `multirow` spanned rows (actually lines in these rows) and also added vertical space where is not needed,
- another (more plausible solution to my opinion) is redesign column widths on the way, that number of lines in cells the second and last column are equal. i do this in *mwe* below assuming that the other text in tables are of similar lengths.

```
\documentclass[10pt, oneside, a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[left=2cm,right=1.5cm,
top=2cm,bottom=2cm,bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{metalogo}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{color,colortbl}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{DarkBlue}{HTML}{074396}
\definecolor{Blue}{HTML}{1C8CCC}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Arial}

\newcommand\ch[1]{\centering
        \begin{tabular}{@{}>{\color{Blue}\bfseries}c@{}}
                    #1
                  \end{tabular}
                  }
\begin{document}

{
\tabulinesep=1.5mm          % <-- changed
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}   % <-- added
\arrayrulecolor{DarkBlue}
 \begin{longtabu} to 170 mm {
    |X[0.8,m]               % <-- changed
    |X[3.5,L,m]             % <-- changed
    |X[1,c,m]               % <-- changed
    |X[1.2,c,m]             % <-- changed
    |X[1.2,c,m]             % <-- changed
    |X[1.5,c,m]             % <-- changed
    |X[3,L,m]|              % <-- changed
    }

\arrayrulecolor{DarkBlue}
\hline

\ch{ID}
& \ch{Message}
& \ch{Mode}
& \ch{Priority}
& \ch{ Category}
& \ch{Escalation}
& \ch{Recommended\\ actions} %<-- changed
 \\
\hline

10003
& ALARM test. Press ALARM button for stop alarm
& All
& Alarm
& A
& Alarm
&  Confirm
 \\
\hline

\multirow{2}{=}[-1ex]{10007}
& \multirow{2}{=}[-1ex]{PORT rudder feedback fail. Check steering system}
& \textcolor{Blue}{\textbf{S}}
& Caution
& B
& *
& \multirow{2}{=}[-1ex]{Switch to MAN, check steering system}
\\

\tabucline{3-6}

&
& \textcolor{Blue}{\textbf{A, F, O}}
& Warning
& B
& Alarm
&
 \\

\hline

\multirow{2}{=}[-1ex]{10007}
& \multirow{2}{=}[-1ex]{PORT rudder feedback fail. Check steering system}
& \textcolor{Blue}{\textbf{S}}
& Caution
& B
& *
& \multirow{2}{=}[-1ex]{Switch to MAN, check steering system}
\\

\tabucline{3-6}

&
& \textcolor{Blue}{\textbf{A, F, O}}
& Warning
& B
& Alarm
&
 \\

\hline
\multirow{2}{=}[-1ex]{10007}
& \multirow{2}{=}[-1ex]{PORT rudder feedback fail. Check steering system}
& \textcolor{Blue}{\textbf{S}}
& Caution
& B
& *
& \multirow{2}{=}[-1ex]{Switch to MAN, check steering system}
\\

\tabucline{3-6}

&
& \textcolor{Blue}{\textbf{A, F, O}}
& Warning
& B
& Alarm
&
 \\ \hline
\end{longtabu}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]