# how to fix the tex vertically in a cell of a table?

Tags: tables, text, fit, cell

this is my problem: I have created a table with excel2latex add for excel but in the first column the text doesn't fit vertically. How can I make the text fit vertically into the first column without adding more rows or columns to the table? I used The Legrand Orange Book template to do my text in latex
can you help me to fix my mistake?

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\caption{Piezas atornilladas comunes y sus dimensiones de instalación}
\label{tab:piezas1}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\thempfootnote}
    \renewcommand*\footnoterule{}
    \scalebox{0.5}{ 
\begin{tabular}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.75cm} >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2.5cm} >{\arraybackslash}m{2.5cm} rccccccccccc}
    \toprule[0.50mm]
    \multicolumn{15}{c}{\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{FiguraA53.png}} \\
    \midrule[0.20mm]
    \multirow{9}[12]{1.75cm}{Tornillo hexagonal DIN EN ISO 4014} & \multicolumn{2}{m{5cm}}{Diámetro nominal de la rosca} & $d_1$    & \textbf{M4}    & \textbf{M5}    & \textbf{M6}    & \textbf{M8}    & \textbf{M10}   & \textbf{M12}   & \textbf{M16}   & \textbf{M20}   & \textbf{M24}   & \textbf{M30}   & \textbf{M36} \\
    \cmidrule[0.20mm]{2-15}          
    & \multirow{2}[2]{2.5cm}{Longitud} & desde & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{$l_1$} & 25    & 25    & 30    & 40    & 45    & 50    & 65    & 80    & 90    & 110   & 140 \\
    &       & hasta &       & 40    & 50    & 60    & 80    & 100   & 120   & 160   & 200   & 240   & 300   & 360 \\
    \cmidrule[0.20mm]{2-15}          
    & \multirow{3}[2]{2.5cm}{Longitud del roscado para:} & $l_1\leqslant 125$ &       & 14    & 16    & 18    & 22    & 26    & 30    & 38    & 46    & 54    & 66    & -- \\
    &       & $125<l_1\leqslant200$ & $b_1$    & --    & --    & --    & 28    & --    & --    & 44    & 52    & 60    & 72    & 84 \\
    &       & $l_1>200$ &       & --    & --    & --    & --    & --    & --    & --    & --    & 73    & 85    & 97 \\
    \cmidrule[0.20mm]{2-15}          
    & \multicolumn{2}{m{5cm}}{Altura de la cabeza} & $k_1$    & 2,8   & 3,5   & 4     & 5,3   & 6,4   & 7,5   & 10    & 13    & 15    & 19    & 23 \\
    \cmidrule[0.20mm]{2-15}          
    & \multicolumn{2}{m{5cm}}{Distancia entre esquinas} & $e_1$    & 7,66  & 8,79  & 11,05 & 14,38 & 17,77 & 20,03 & 26,75 & 33,53 & 39,98 & 50,85 & 60,79 \\
    \cmidrule[0.20mm]{2-15}          
    & \multicolumn{2}{m{5cm}}{Ancho de llave} & $s$     & 7     & 8     & 10    & 13    & 16    & 18    & 24    & 30    & 36    & 46    & 55 \\
    \midrule[0.20mm]
    \multirow{2}[4]{1.75cm}{Tuerca hexagonal DIN EN ISO 4032} & \multicolumn{2}{m{5cm}}{Altura de la tuerca} & $m$     & 3,2   & 4,7   & 5,2   & 6,8   & 8,4   & 10,8  & 14,8  & 18    & 21,5  & 25,6  & 31 \\
    \cmidrule[0.20mm]{2-15}          
    & \multicolumn{2}{m{5cm}}{Saliente mínimo del tornillo} & $v$     & 4,6   & 6,3   & 7,2   & 9,3   & 11,4  & 14,3  & 18,8  & 23    & 27,5  & 32,6  & 39 \\
    \midrule[0.20mm]
    \multirow{6}[8]{1.75cm}{Tornillo cilíndrico con hexágono hueco interior DIN EN ISO 4762} & \multirow{2}[2]{2.5cm}{Longitud} & desde & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{$l_2$} & 6     & 8     & 10    & 12    & 16    & 20    & 25    & 30    & 40    & 45    & 45 \\
    &       & hasta &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{40} & 50    & 60    & 80    & 100   & 120   & 160   & 250   & 250   & 200   & 200 \\
    \cmidrule[0.20mm]{2-15}          
    & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\multirow{2}[2]{5cm}{Longitud del roscado}} & $b_2$    & 20    & 22    & 24    & 28    & 32    & 36    & 44    & 52    & 60    & 72    & 84 \\
    & &  & para $l_2$ & $\geqslant30$  & $\geqslant30$  & $\geqslant35$  & $\geqslant40$  & $\geqslant45$  & $\geqslant55$  & $\geqslant65$  & $\geqslant80$  & $\geqslant90$  & $\geqslant110$ & $\geqslant120$ \\
    \cmidrule[0.20mm]{2-15}          
    & \multicolumn{2}{m{5cm}}{Altura de la cabeza} & $k_2$    & 4     & 5     & 6     & 8     & 10    & 12    & 16    & 20    & 24    & 30    & 36 \\
    \cmidrule[0.20mm]{2-15}         
     & \multicolumn{2}{m{5cm}}{Diámetro de la cabeza}       & $d_2$    & 7     & 8,5   & 10    & 13    & 16    & 18    & 24    & 30    & 36    & 45    & 54 \\
    \midrule[0.20mm]
    \multirow{6}[8]{1.75cm}{Espárragos DIN 938} & \multirow{2}[2]{2.5cm}{Longitud} & desde & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{$l$} & 20    & 22    & 25    & 30    & 35    & 40    & 50    & 60    & 70    & 85    & 100 \\
    &       & hasta &       & 40    & 50    & 60    & 80    & 100   & 120   & 160   & 200   & 200   & 300   & 360 \\
    \cmidrule[0.20mm]{2-15}          
    & \multirow{2}[2]{2.5cm}{Longitud del roscado para:} & $l\leqslant125$ & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{$b_2$} & 14    & 16    & 18    & 22    & 26    & 30    & 38    & 46    & 54    & 66    & 78 \\
    &       & $125<l\leqslant200$ &       & 20    & 22    & 24    & 28    & 32    & 36    & 44    & 52    & 60    & 72    & 84 \\
    \cmidrule[0.20mm]{2-15}          
    & \multicolumn{2}{m{5cm}}{longitud extremo atornillable $\approx1\cdot d$} & $b_1$    & 4     & 5     & 6     & 8     & 10    & 12    & 16    & 20    & 24    & 30    & 36 \\
    \cmidrule[0.20mm]{2-15}          
    & \multicolumn{2}{m{5cm}}{Salida de rosca ($\approx2,5\cdot P$)} & $x_1$    & 1,75  & 2     & 2,5   & 3,2   & 3,8   & 4,3   & 5     & 6,3   & 7,5   & 9     & 10 \\
    \midrule[0.20mm]
    \multirow{7}[14]{1.75cm}{Salida de rosca y ranuras de rosca   DIN 76-1} & \multicolumn{2}{m{5cm}}{Exceso de longitud del orificio base} & $e_3$    & 3,8   & 4,2   & 5,1   & 6,2   & 7,3   & 8,3   & 9,3   & 11,2  & 13,1  & 15,2  & 16,8 \\
    \cmidrule[0.20mm]{2-15}          
    & \multicolumn{2}{m{5cm}}{Diámetro de ranuras} & $g_1$    & 4,3   & 5,3   & 6,5   & 8,5   & 10,5  & 12,5  & 16,5  & 20,5  & 24,5  & 30,5  & 36,5 \\
    \cmidrule[0.20mm]{2-15}         
    & \multicolumn{2}{m{5cm}}{Ancho de ranuras ($4\cdot P$)} & $f_1$    & 2,8   & 3,2   & 4     & 5     & 6     & 7     & 8     & 10    & 12    & 14    & 16 \\
    \cmidrule[0.20mm]{2-15}          
    & \multicolumn{2}{m{5cm}}{redondeos} & $r_1$    & 0,35  & 0,4   & 0,5   & 0,6   & 0,75  & 0,9   & 1     & 1,25  & 1,5   & 1,75  & 2 \\
    \cmidrule[0.20mm]{2-15}          
    & \multicolumn{2}{m{5cm}}{Diámetro de ranuras} & $g_2$    & 2,9   & 3,7   & 4,4   & 6     & 7,7   & 9,4   & 13    & 16,4  & 19,6  & 25    & 30,3 \\
    \cmidrule[0.20mm]{2-15}          
    & \multicolumn{2}{m{5cm}}{Ancho de ranuras ($3,5\cdot P$)} & $f_2$    & 2,45  & 2,8   & 3,5   & 4,4   & 5,2   & 6,1   & 7     & 8,7   & 10,5  & 12    & 14 \\
    \cmidrule[0.20mm]{2-15}          
    & \multicolumn{2}{l}{redondeos ($\approx0,5P$)} & $r_2$    & 0,4   & 0,4   & 0,6   & 0,6   & 0,8   & 1     & 1     & 1,2   & 1,6   & 1,6   & 2 \\
    \midrule[0.20mm]
    \multirow{6}[12]{1.75cm}{Cajeras para tornillo hexagonal y tornillo de cabeza cilindrica hueca DIN 974-1 DIN 974-2} & \multicolumn{2}{m{5cm}}{Agujero pasante} & $d_4$    & 4,5   & 5,5   & 6,6   & 9     & 11    & 13,5  & 17,5  & 22    & 26    & 33    & 39 \\
    \cmidrule[0.20mm]{2-15}          
    & \multicolumn{2}{m{5cm}}{Diámetro cajera, fila 3} & $d_3$    & 10    & 11    & 13    & 18    & 22    & 26    & 33    & 40    & 48    & 61    & 73 \\
    \cmidrule[0.20mm]{2-15}          
    & \multicolumn{2}{m{5cm}}{Diámetro cajera, fila 1} & $d_5$    & 13    & 15    & 18    & 24    & 28    & 33    & 40    & 46    & 73    & 71    & 82 \\
    \cmidrule[0.20mm]{2-15}          
    & \multicolumn{2}{m{5cm}}{Profundidad de cajera} & $t_3$    & 3,2   & 3,9   & 4,4   & 5,9   & 7     & 8,1   & 10,6  & 13,6  & 15,8  & 20    & 24 \\
    \cmidrule[0.20mm]{2-15}          
    & \multicolumn{2}{m{5cm}}{Diámetro cajera} & $d_6$    & 8     & 10    & 11    & 15    & 18    & 20    & 26    & 33    & 40    & 50    & 58 \\
    \cmidrule[0.20mm]{2-15}         
    & \multicolumn{2}{m{5cm}}{Profundidad de cajera} & $t_4$    & 4,4   & 5,4   & 6,4   & 8,6   & 10,6  & 12,6  & 16,6  & 20,6  & 24,8  & 34    & 37 \\
    \midrule[0.20mm]
    \multirow{2}[4]{1.75cm}{Arandelas DIN EN ISO 7089 y DIN EN ISO 7090} & \multicolumn{2}{m{5cm}}{Diámetro exterior} & $d_g$    & 9     & 10    & 12    & 16    & 20    & 24    & 30    & 37    & 44    & 56    & 66 \\
    \cmidrule[0.20mm]{2-15}          
    & \multicolumn{2}{m{5cm}}{Espesor} & $s_2$    & 0,8   & 1     & 1,6   & 1,6   & 2     & 2,5   & 3     & 3     & 4     & 4     & 5 \\
    \bottomrule[0.50mm]
\end{tabular}}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
```

[image: this is the result]

Comment: Welcome! Please edit your code to make your snippet compilable. Also, what exactly do you want to do? That is, what constitutes a fix? Do you want that column to be wider? Do you want to add rows to the table? Or what?

Comment: Probably related: [Text in multirow overlaps the next row](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/113705/134144)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- it is difficult to help you without knowing your document page layout. in mwe below i suppose, that the page is A$ size and that text borders has 20 mm width
- your main problem is that width of the first column is to small and width of the second and the third to big. i suggest to increase the width of the first column and for width of the second and third column use to their natural width (i.e. use `l` column type)
- determine table width use of `tabular*` table environment
- reduce size of `\tabcolsep`, i.e.: initialy set it to zero and than left its calculation to `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}`
- use smaller font: `\footnotesize`
- remove `minipage` and `\scalebox{0.5}{...}`
- break some longer text in multi column cells in two lines (by use of `\makecell`)

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
  \usepackage{amssymb}
  \usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow}
  \newcommand\mcc[1]{\multicolumn{2}{l}{#1}}

  %---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
  \usepackage{showframe}
  \renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
  \renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
  %---------------------------------------------------------------%

  \begin{document}
  \begin{table}[h!]
  \caption{Piezas atornilladas comunes y sus dimensiones de instalación}
  \label{tab:piezas1}

  \footnotesize
  \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
  \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
      p{3.5cm}
      p{2cm}
      l
      rc cc cc cc cc cc
                              }
      \toprule
  \multirow{13}{=}{Tornillo hexagonal\newline DIN EN ISO 4014}
      & \mcc{Diámetro nominal de la rosca}
      & $d_1$    & \textbf{M4}    & \textbf{M5}    & \textbf{M6}    & \textbf{M8}    & \textbf{M10}   & \textbf{M12}   & \textbf{M16}   & \textbf{M20}   & \textbf{M24}   & \textbf{M30}   & \textbf{M36} \\
      \cmidrule{2-15}
      & \multirow{2}{=}{Longitud}
      & desde & \multirow{2}{*}{$l_1$} & 25    & 25    & 30    & 40    & 45    & 50    & 65    & 80    & 90    & 110   & 140 \\
      &     & hasta &       & 40    & 50    & 60    & 80    & 100   & 120   & 160   & 200   & 240   & 300   & 360 \\
      \cmidrule{2-15}
      & \multirow{3}{=}{Longitud del roscado para:}
      & $l_1\leqslant 125$ &       & 14    & 16    & 18    & 22    & 26    & 30    & 38    & 46    & 54    & 66    & -- \\
      &    & $125<l_1\leqslant200$ & $b_1$    & --    & --    & --    & 28    & --    & --    & 44    & 52    & 60    & 72 & 84 \\
      &    & $l_1>200$ &       & --    & --    & --    & --    & --    & --    & --    & --    & 73    & 85    & 97 \\
      \cmidrule{2-15}
      & \mcc{Altura de la cabeza} & $k_1$    & 2,8   & 3,5   & 4     & 5,3   & 6,4   & 7,5   & 10    & 13    & 15    & 19    & 23 \\
      \cmidrule{2-15}
      & \mcc{Distancia entre esquinas} & $e_1$    & 7,66  & 8,79  & 11,05 & 14,38 & 17,77 & 20,03 & 26,75 & 33,53 & 39,98 & 50,85 & 60,79 \\
      \cmidrule{2-15}
      & \mcc{Ancho de llave} & $s$     & 7     & 8     & 10    & 13    & 16    & 18    & 24    & 30    & 36    & 46    & 55 \\
      \midrule
  \multirow{2.5}{=}{Tuerca hexagonal\newline DIN EN ISO 4032}
      & \mcc{Altura de la tuerca} & $m$     & 3,2   & 4,7   & 5,2   & 6,8   & 8,4   & 10,8  & 14,8  & 18    & 21,5  & 25,6  & 31 \\
      \cmidrule{2-15}
      & \mcc{Saliente mínimo del tornillo} & $v$     & 4,6   & 6,3   & 7,2   & 9,3   & 11,4  & 14,3  & 18,8  & 23    & 27,5  & 32,6  & 39 \\
      \midrule
  \multirow{7}{=}{Tornillo cilíndrico con hexágono hueco interior DIN EN ISO 4762}
      & \multirow{2}{=}{Longitud} & desde & \multirow{2}{*}{$l_2$} & 6     & 8     & 10    & 12    & 16    & 20    & 25    & 30    & 40    & 45    & 45 \\
      &       & hasta &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{40} & 50    & 60    & 80    & 100   & 120   & 160   & 250   & 250   & 200   & 200 \\
      \cmidrule{2-15}
      & \mcc{\multirow{2}{*}{Longitud del roscado}} & $b_2$    & 20    & 22    & 24    & 28    & 32    & 36    & 44    & 52    & 60    & 72    & 84 \\
      & &  & para $l_2$ & $\geqslant30$  & $\geqslant30$  & $\geqslant35$  & $\geqslant40$  & $\geqslant45$  & $\geqslant55$  & $\geqslant65$  & $\geqslant80$  & $\geqslant90$  & $\geqslant110$ & $\geqslant120$ \\
      \cmidrule{2-15}
      & \mcc{Altura de la cabeza} & $k_2$    & 4     & 5     & 6     & 8     & 10    & 12    & 16    & 20    & 24    & 30    & 36 \\
      \cmidrule{2-15}
       & \mcc{Diámetro de la cabeza}       & $d_2$    & 7     & 8,5   & 10    & 13    & 16    & 18    & 24    & 30    & 36    & 45    & 54 \\
      \midrule
  \multirow{8}{=}{Espárragos DIN 938}
      & \multirow{2}{=}{Longitud} & desde & \multirow{2}{*}{$l$} & 20    & 22    & 25    & 30    & 35    & 40    & 50    & 60    & 70    & 85    & 100 \\
      &       & hasta &       & 40    & 50    & 60    & 80    & 100   & 120   & 160   & 200   & 200   & 300   & 360 \\
      \cmidrule{2-15}
      & \multirow{2}{=}{Longitud del roscado para:}
      & $l\leqslant125$ & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{$b_2$} & 14    & 16    & 18    & 22    & 26    & 30    & 38    & 46    & 54    & 66    & 78 \\
      &       & $125<l\leqslant200$ &       & 20    & 22    & 24    & 28    & 32    & 36    & 44    & 52    & 60    & 72    & 84 \\
      \cmidrule{2-15}
      & \mcc{\makecell[l]{longitud extremo\\ atornillable $\approx1\cdot d$}}
      & $b_1$    & 4     & 5     & 6     & 8     & 10    & 12    & 16    & 20    & 24    & 30    & 36 \\
      \cmidrule{2-15}
      & \mcc{Salida de rosca ($\approx2,5\cdot P$)}
      & $x_1$    & 1,75  & 2     & 2,5   & 3,2   & 3,8   & 4,3   & 5     & 6,3   & 7,5   & 9     & 10 \\
      \midrule
  \multirow{10}{=}{Salida de rosca y ranuras de rosca   DIN 76-1}
      & \mcc{\makecell[l]{Exceso de longitud\\ del orificio base}}
      & $e_3$    & 3,8   & 4,2   & 5,1   & 6,2   & 7,3   & 8,3   & 9,3   & 11,2  & 13,1  & 15,2  & 16,8 \\
      \cmidrule{2-15}
      & \mcc{Diámetro de ranuras}
      & $g_1$    & 4,3   & 5,3   & 6,5   & 8,5   & 10,5  & 12,5  & 16,5  & 20,5  & 24,5  & 30,5  & 36,5 \\
      \cmidrule{2-15}
      & \mcc{Ancho de ranuras ($4\cdot P$)}
      & $f_1$    & 2,8   & 3,2   & 4     & 5     & 6     & 7     & 8     & 10    & 12    & 14    & 16 \\
      \cmidrule{2-15}
      & \mcc{redondeos}
      & $r_1$    & 0,35  & 0,4   & 0,5   & 0,6   & 0,75  & 0,9   & 1     & 1,25  & 1,5   & 1,75  & 2 \\
      \cmidrule{2-15}
      & \mcc{Diámetro de ranuras} & $g_2$    & 2,9   & 3,7   & 4,4   & 6     & 7,7   & 9,4   & 13    & 16,4  & 19,6  & 25    & 30,3 \\
      \cmidrule{2-15}
      & \mcc{Ancho de ranuras ($3,5\cdot P$)}
      & $f_2$    & 2,45  & 2,8   & 3,5   & 4,4   & 5,2   & 6,1   & 7     & 8,7   & 10,5  & 12    & 14 \\
      \cmidrule{2-15}
      & \mcc{redondeos ($\approx0,5P$)}
      & $r_2$    & 0,4   & 0,4   & 0,6   & 0,6   & 0,8   & 1     & 1     & 1,2   & 1,6   & 1,6   & 2 \\
    \midrule
  \multirow{8}{=}{Cajeras para tornillo hexagonal y tornillo de cabeza cilindrica hueca DIN 974-1 DIN 974-2}
      & \mcc{Agujero pasante} & $d_4$    & 4,5   & 5,5   & 6,6   & 9     & 11    & 13,5  & 17,5  & 22    & 26    & 33    & 39 \\
      \cmidrule{2-15}
      & \mcc{Diámetro cajera, fila 3} & $d_3$    & 10    & 11    & 13    & 18    & 22    & 26    & 33    & 40    & 48    & 61    & 73 \\
      \cmidrule{2-15}
      & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Diámetro cajera, fila 1} & $d_5$    & 13    & 15    & 18    & 24    & 28    & 33    & 40    & 46    & 73    & 71    & 82 \\
      \cmidrule{2-15}
      & \mcc{Profundidad de cajera} & $t_3$    & 3,2   & 3,9   & 4,4   & 5,9   & 7     & 8,1   & 10,6  & 13,6  & 15,8  & 20    & 24 \\
      \cmidrule{2-15}
      & \mcc{Diámetro cajera} & $d_6$    & 8     & 10    & 11    & 15    & 18    & 20    & 26    & 33    & 40    & 50    & 58 \\
      \cmidrule{2-15}
      & \mcc{Profundidad de cajera} & $t_4$    & 4,4   & 5,4   & 6,4   & 8,6   & 10,6  & 12,6  & 16,6  & 20,6  & 24,8  & 34    & 37 \\
      \midrule
  \multirow{2}{=}{Arandelas DIN EN ISO 7089 y DIN EN ISO 7090}
      & \mcc{Diámetro exterior} & $d_g$    & 9     & 10    & 12    & 16    & 20    & 24    & 30    & 37    & 44    & 56    & 66 \\
      \cmidrule{2-15}
      & \mcc{Espesor} & $s_2$    & 0,8   & 1     & 1,6   & 1,6   & 2     & 2,5   & 3     & 3     & 4     & 4     & 5 \\
      \bottomrule
  \end{tabular*}


  \end{table}
  \end{document}
  ```

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! and sorry for omitting information about the latex file like the page size

Comment: @JorgeLlimpeRojas, you are welcome. i only don't know, if my guessing about your page layout is correct. if it is not, than can happen, that table will not look so nice ... if answer help you (solve your problem), you can consider to accept it (by clicking on check mark at top left side of answer) :-)